# jQuery not getting reply when using asynchronous

Tags: jquery, asynchronous

I am using this code to get response back from server. But I want that asynchronously as I need to show progress. When I use this code, I don't get any messsage back from server (only getting alert as object). Here is my code. Any ideas?

```
var msg = $.ajax({
    type: 'POST',
    url: '../pages/registration.php',
    async: true,
    data: {
        do: 'register'
    },
    beforeSend: function () {
        $("#Progress").show();
    },
    success: function (data, status) {
        $("#Progress").hide();
        $("#AckMsg").html(data);
    }
});
alert("aa" + msg);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As of jQuery 1.5, a XMLHttpRequest (jqXHR) object is returned by $.ajax(). This is the object you assign to your var msg, and later put in the alert. Hence you get "alert as object" as you describe it. If you want to alert what is returned by the server, do:

```
success: function (data, status) {
    $("#Progress").hide();
    $("#AckMsg").html(data);
    alert(data);
}
```

If this alerts data as empty or undefined. Check your ajax call URL.

```
url: '../pages/registration.php',
```

I believe using a relative URL like this will make a ajax request to http://www.yoursite.com/../pages/registration.php for example. This is most likely not what you want to do.

Answer (score 1):

Use the Developer tools available in almost all browsers now, to figure out exactly what Url is being used by ajax.
My guess is your '..'s in the url seem suspicious.

Comment: thankx, the url is correct, when i set the async to true, i am getting response, but i cant use that as i need to show progress here.

Comment: Well you your question is unclear then.  IN your questions you say you are not getting a message (is it not same is response?) back.

Comment: Thanks, The question is  "when i set the async to false, i am getting response" but not when async is true.

Answer (score 1):

Put the alert in success callback.Since its an async call you can only catch the response in success callback.

```
success: function (data, status) {
        $("#Progress").hide();
        alert(data);// or you can write 'debugger' here if you are using firebug will break at this point and you can check what your remote call is returning.
        $("#AckMsg").html(data);
    }
```

Also in firebug go to console,you can check request and response of your call.
In case you are not used to firebug,try using Developer tools in IE or Chrome.

Comment: thanks, i already tried it, but am getting into that part.Not even getting and alert message.

Comment: Try adding the ajax error callback,and find out what error you are getting

Answer (score 1):

Maybe you should hook a function up to the fail event.

```
msg.fail(function(jqXHR, textStatus) 
{ 
    alert( "Request failed: " + textStatus ); 
});
```

Comment: hi, Event it doesn't going to fail function