# jQuery ajax request only works synchronously, doesn't return when asynchronous

Tags: jquery, asynchronous

I am making a request via jQuery ajax to a .NET generic handler (.ashx).

I am returning JSON, which I have validated on JSONLint, but can not post as it is sensitive data.

The problem is that the call only returns when done synchronousely (`async:false`).  When done asynchronously it never comes back.  `async:false` will call my success function as well as all the global functions.  `async:true` will only call global functions `ajaxStart` and `ajaxSend`, `async:false` will call those as well as the others.

I have little idea how to further debug or determine why there is no response coming back.

```
$.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    async: false,
    cache: false,
    timout: 600000,
    data: request_object.GetQueryString(),
    dataType: "json",
    responseType: "json",
    error: function (request, error_type, error_message) {
        alert("error");
    },
    success: function (data, status, request) {
        alert("success");
    },
    url: "./ReportRequestHandler.ashx",
    complete: function () {
        alert("here");
    }
});

$(document).ajaxError(function () {
    alert("ajaxError");
}).ajaxSend(function () {
    alert("ajaxSend");
}).ajaxStart(function () {
    alert("ajaxStart");
}).ajaxStop(function () {
    alert("ajaxStop");
}).ajaxSuccess(function () {
    alert("ajaxSuccess");
}).ajaxComplete(function () {
    alert("ajaxComplete");
});
```

Comment: there is spelling mistake in timeout .. also . check in net panel of firebug or in console of chrome for xhr request so that you can know what is the issue

Answer (score 0):

I think its because of the "." in the URL. Did you try removing that? Check this as well they has something similar

[jQuery not getting reply when using asynchronous](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8629576/jquery-not-getting-reply-when-using-asynchronous?rq=1)

Hope it helps

Comment: The button I was using was submitting the page during the request in async and of course sync was holding it in place long enough to respond.  Page was so short that it loaded to fast to see the blip.

Answer (score 0):

I ran the code in a page with the your configurations sans async attribute and it seems to be working fine for me..

```
<%@ Page Language="C#" AutoEventWireup="true" CodeFile="Default.aspx.cs" Inherits="Pages" %>

<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head runat="server">

    <script type="text/javascript" src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.8.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

    <title></title>

    <script type="text/javascript">
        $(document).ajaxError(function() {
            alert("ajaxError");
        }).ajaxSend(function() {
            alert("ajaxSend");
        }).ajaxStart(function() {
            alert("ajaxStart");
        }).ajaxStop(function() {
            alert("ajaxStop");
        }).ajaxSuccess(function() {
            alert("ajaxSuccess");
        }).ajaxComplete(function() {
            alert("ajaxComplete");
        });
        $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            timout: 600000,
            data: { 'type': 'check' },
            dataType: "json",
            responseType: "json",
            error: function(request, error_type, error_message) {
                alert("error");
            },
            success: function(data, status, request) {
                alert("success");
            },
            url: "../../Ajax/GenericData.ashx",
            complete: function() {
                alert("here");
            }
        });

    </script>

</head>
<body>
    <form id="form1" runat="server">
    <div>
        <asp:ScriptManager ID="ScriptManager1" runat="server" />
    </div>
    </form>
</body>
</html>
```

I got all the alert messages in order.. Can you check the console section of the browser and see whats going on exactly with you request when  async:false is removed from your configuration..

Comment: Place a debug point in the .ashx and see if the point is hit when the request starts for both types

Answer (score 0):

I found the problem.
The button used to trigger the event was submitting the page and reloading too fast for me to see any blink.